# Record Audio from Peppers Tablet Microphone

Tags: python, speech-recognition, tablet, microphone, pepper

I would like to use the microphone of peppers tablet to implement speech recognition.
I already do speech recognition with the microphones in the head. 
But the audio I get from the head microphones is noisy due to the fans in the head and peppers joints movement.

Does anybody know how to capture the audio from peppers tablet?

I am using `Pepper 2.5.` and would like to solve this with `python`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With NAOqi 2.5 on Pepper it is not possible to access the tablet's microphone.
You can either upgrade to 2.9.x and use the Android API for this, or stay in 2.5 and use Python to get the sound from Pepper's microphones.